# Android how to filter which preferences are displayed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, checkboxpreference

I have 2 preference pages. Depending on a checkbox displayed on the preference page "one" I want to display a CheckBoxPreference or not display it on the page "two". I know that I should add on the activity of the page "two" a way to handle if the checkbox in the page "one" is checked or not. But i don't know how to refer on that checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Save the checkbox's state by getting a reference to it programmatically, save it's state as a preference, pass it in an intent (via `intent.putExtras();`) or save it in SharedPreferences, then on the second activity check if the CheckBoxPreference.isChecked() then conditionally load preferences. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html) for more information.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to do this? My problem is that i don't know how to refer in a CheckBoxPreference from the xml.

Comment: You refer to a CheckBoxPreference the same way you refer to any other object that is defined in XML eg: CheckBoxPreference checkBox = (CheckBoxPreference) findViewById(R.id.yourCheckBox).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class named StaticValues and add a variable that it is boolean.

```
public static boolean isCheckBoxChecked;
```

When the checkbox is checked set this variable true:

```
StaticValues.isCheckBoxChecked = true;
```

When you are displaying preference page 2 you can check this variable and deside if you diplay the next checkbox or not.